How to extend an object type with string literal type?
I have the following code. Type B should extend type A while extending the acceptable values for property type. But the assignment is giving me type error.
type A = {
    type: 'error' | 'operator';
}

type B = A & {
    type: 'something';
    record: string;
}

let b: B;

// The following assignments should have no error.
b = {
    type: 'something',
    record: 'abc'
}

b = {
    type: 'error',
    record: 'abc'
}

b = {
    type: 'operator',
    record: 'abc'
}


A & {type: 'something'} doesn't mean what you think it means. Intersections of distinct string literal types are impossible (intersection means "and", not "or"), so you're essentially defining B to be {type: never, record: string}. You can't do what you're doing with an intersection. What are you trying to support here? Do you want B to require record? Do you only want record to be required when type is "something"? Do you want record to be considered an excess property when type is not "something"? We need more details here; please [edit] to provide them.

Update
As pointed out I made a mistake in my original answer by reading type B = A | {...} instead of type B = A & {...}
So now the best answer is the comment by @jcalz under your question, which states that & is in fact an intersection, and type A and { type: 'something'; record: string; } have nothing in common, so the resulting type is never, as you can see by the intellisense in the playground.
Maybe you still want to achieve what I thought initially, so I keep the original answer below.
Original answer (type B = A | {...})
The problem is that the second and third assignments do not match the definition of B, and that's expected because of how the | operator works. Type B in your case can only have one property "type" with possible values 'error' and 'operator' (that's type A), or the property "type" with fixed value 'something' and an additional "record" property, but you cannot mix those types.
You need to redefine B like this:
type B = {
   type: A["type"] | 'something';
   record: string;
}

Note that this means that you must always provide a value for the property "record", so now the following assignment will fail:
b = {
   type: 'error'
}

If you also want to support the plain A type, you need to put back the | operator:
type B = A | {
   type: A["type"] | 'something';
   record: string;
}


I tried this. It doesn't work for the second and third case when type 'A' does not have record property.

"that's […] how the | operator works" - notice OP is using & not |. Otherwise, your first snippet is spot on.

"It doesn't work for the second and third case when type 'A' does not have record property" Huh? If I try the suggestion here as shown in the playground then your three examples work fine. What is the problem?

@Bergi thanks for pointing out my mistake, I updated the answer
